# Strongloop querying data with (or) and (and) at the same time

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I need to do this.

```
select * 
from person 
where (firstname like '%a' or lastname like "%a") and id NOT IN (1 , 2)
```

node.js:

```
   BegroupdUser.find({
        limit: limit,
        skip: skip,
        where: {
            id: { nin: adminIds },
            or: [{
                firstName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}
            }, {
                lastName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}
            }]
        }
    }, function (errors, users) {
  });
```

Comment: Try this {
  "where": {
    "and": [
      {
        "id": {
          "nin":  "adminIds"
        }
      },
      {
        "or": [{
                firstName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}}, 
                {
                lastName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}}
              ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "where": {
    "and": [
      {
        "id": {
          "nin":  adminIds
        }
      },
      {
        "or": [{
                firstName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}}, 
                {
                lastName: {like: '%' + _query + '%'}}
              ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading this: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-and/or

It looks like you need to nest your `or` inside the `and` and use a regex instead of the `like` operator.